# SQL results in one row

Tags: sql

I have following statement:

```
SELECT        
    Person.PersonID, Person.PersonName, Person.Surname, 
    Address.Street, Address.PostCode,
    (SELECT Phones.Num
     WHERE (Phones.CommunicationTypeId = '78')) AS email, 
    (SELECT Phones.Num
     WHERE (Phones.CommunicationTypeId = '83')) AS mobile,
    (SELECT Phones.Num
     WHERE (Phones.CommunicationTypeId = '88')) AS phone
FROM     
    Address 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    Person ON Address.ObjectId = Person.PersonID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    Phones ON Person.PersonID = Phones.ObjectID
```

Now results shows separate rows, while I want to have it in one row:

[image]

How to consolidate it into just one row?

Comment: If it's always 1 row with a value and another with `null`, you can use `max` and `group by`. If you can have multiple not null values you'll have to decide what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your person has more than one corresponding phone records (I guess 2 records with different types.

```
SELECT 
    ObjectID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CommunicationTypeId = '78' THEN Num ELSE null END) as email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CommunicationTypeId = '83' THEN Num ELSE null END) as mobile,
    MAX(CASE WHEN CommunicationTypeId = '88' THEN Num ELSE null END) as phone
FROM Phones
GROUP BY ObjectID
```

The select above returns 3 columns for each person and you can use it in the main query

```
SELECT     
    Person.PersonID, Person.PersonName, Person.Surname, 
    Address.Street, Address.PostCode,
    Phones.email, Phones mobile, Phones.phone
FROM
    Address 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    Person ON Address.ObjectId = Person.PersonID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (sub query above) Phones ON Person.PersonID = Phones.ObjectID
```